# How to, for all the null values (NaN) in column, get the respective values which exist in a different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, vlookup

I have a dataframe with NaN values which i need to assign. The way i need to assign these values depend on the column 'code'. The NaN values exist in a different dataframe and the same column 'code'.

My initial dataframe with NaN values but not in all rows (third row has values for column 'capital' and 'country' :
[image]

I want to assign values from the dataframe below:
[image]

The end result is something like this:
[image]

I have tried with:

```
df1['capital'] = np.where(df1['capital'].isnull() == True, df1['code'].map(df2['capital']), df1['capital']
```

but i get a syntax error: 'keyword can't be an expression'.

any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

Option 1

```
df1.columns=df2.columns
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0).dropna(axis=0)
```

Option 2

```
df1.set_index('code').captial.fillna(df2.set_index('col2').captial)
Out[184]: 
code
0    B
1    C
2    A
3    D
4    E
Name: captial, dtype: object
```

Data Input :

```
d1 = {'code' : [0,1,2,3,4],
         'captial' : [np.nan,np.nan,'A',np.nan,np.nan]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
d2 = {'col2' : [0,1,3,4],
         'captial' : ['B','C','D','E']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Comment: pd.concat will change the shape of the initial dataframe. is there a way not to, something like a vlookup in excel?

Comment: @dapaz please check `pd.lookup`